# How to create database with slick

Tags: scala, slick

I tried to create database with slick with following code

Part of my build dependecies

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.12"
```

_

```
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "user", "password")
val dbName = "database1"
Await.result(db.run(sqlu"CREATE DATABASE $dbName"), 1.second)
```

User have all privileges on *.*

But it throws exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Invoker.first
   at slick.jdbc.Invoker.first(Invoker.scala:34)
   at slick.jdbc.Invoker.first$(Invoker.scala:30)
   at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
   at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:52)
   at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:51)
   at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:240)
   at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:240) java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Please tell me how to create database without exception.
I want to create one database per user so I cannot write database name in `application.conf`

Comment: Wich version of slick do you use?

Comment: Slick version is 3.2.2. I use slick via Play Slick 3.0.0

Comment: Could you please include the build definition?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go through 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlick . 
Set the database configuration in `application.conf` correctly

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
 slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demoDBName"
 slick.dbs.default.db.user = "root user name"
 slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
```

This will create `demoDBName` while runnung your application if it doesn't exists. Hope it helps.